# Neural network converges to 0.5 for XoR

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm coding a neural network in C for an OCR project. Before testing with character recognition, I'm making it learn the XoR operation. Although, the results I'n getting always converges to 0.5 instead of 1 or 0 for all input combinations.

I'm using a learning rate of 0.35 and the activation function is the standard sigmoid function (1/(1+exp(-x)). The network has 2 inputs, 1 bias neurone, 1 hidden layer with 2 neurones and 1 output neurone.

The algorithm for learning the operations looks like this:

```
initialise network with random weights
while networks doesn't know all operations with 5% precision do:
    compute output for all combinations
    run the retropropagation algorithm for all combinations
endwhile
```

I've tried to change the learning rate and the activation function, but none of that solved the issue. Why does the network keeps converging to 0.5 and how can I solve that?

Comment: XOR needs at least 2 layers of nuerons: one layer to AND the inputs with one input inverted and one layer to OR them

Comment: what do you mean by "input inverted"?

Comment: Inverted means 1 is 0 and 0 is 1.

Comment: place your snippet of code, this way we can help better!

Comment: For future viewers, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369335/xor-neural-network-converges-to-0-5) has some answers. Perhaps something is wrong with your activation function, or your usage of it. Also, in my experience, I find that ReLU is a much more effective activation function for the XOR problem.